# Execute a node.js API against a specific operating system

Tags: node.js

Is it possible to set an environment variable/or some other mechanism, call a node.js API such as `path.dirname('xyz')`, have it execute as if it was running under that operating system and then unset the variable to return node.js to normal?

Comment: If I understand what you are asking, I can't see that working (although possibly depends on the APIs). The implementation detail of some APIs are dictated by the operating system itself, not Node, Nodes just delegating the call.

Comment: I'm not really following what you're asking.  Can you provide an example of what you're trying to do?